# how to change/set autocomplete jquery combobox value using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete

I have a autocomplete Jquery comboxbox. How to change/set the value for autocomplete using jquery.

I have tried below code but not working

Select code which is displayed using Jquery custom combobox:

```
 <select id="comboboxProv" style="width:300px;" >
 <option value="1" selected>1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>
```

code to change autocomplete value which is not working

```
$('#comboboxProv').data('custom.combobox').value("Small");
```

Code to create jquery autocomplete combobox

```
(function( $ ) {
$.widget( "custom.combobox", {
  _create: function() {
    this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
      .insertAfter( this.element );

    this.element.hide();
    this._createAutocomplete();
    this._createShowAllButton();
  },

  _createAutocomplete: function() {
    var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
      value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

    this.input = $( "<input>" )
      .appendTo( this.wrapper )
      .val( value )
      .attr( "title", "" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
      .autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
      })
      /*.tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
      });*/

    this._on( this.input, {
      autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.item.option.selected = true;
    //   alert(ui.item);

        this._trigger( "select", event, {
          item: ui.item.option
        });
      },

      autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
    });
  },

  _createShowAllButton: function() {
    var input = this.input,
      wasOpen = false;

    $( "<a>" )
      .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
      //.attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
      .tooltip()
      .appendTo( this.wrapper )
      .button({
        icons: {
          primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
        },
        text: false
      })
      .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
      .mousedown(function() {
        wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
      })
      .click(function() {
        input.focus();

        // Close if already visible
        if ( wasOpen ) {
          return;
        }

        // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
        input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
      });
  },

  _source: function( request, response ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
    response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
      var text = $( this ).text();
      if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
        return {
          label: text,
          value: text,
          option: this
        };
    }) );
  },

  _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

    // Selected an item, nothing to do
    if ( ui.item ) {
      return;
    }

    // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
    var value = this.input.val(),
      valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
      valid = false;
    this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
      if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
        this.selected = valid = true;
        return false;
      }
    });

    // Found a match, nothing to do
    if ( valid ) {
      return;
    }

    // Remove invalid value
    this.input
      .val( "" )
      .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
      .tooltip( "open" );
    this.element.val( "" );
    this._delay(function() {
      this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
    }, 2500 );
    this.input.data( "ui-autocomplete" ).term = "";
  },

  _destroy: function() {
    this.wrapper.remove();
    this.element.show();
  }
});
})( jQuery );
```

How to change value of autocomplete jquery combobox

I have referred to one of the working jfiddle but even that is not working for me

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197664/set-value-to-jquery-autocomplete-combobox)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To change the value of the combobox based on the selection in the  drop down, this should do the trick:

```
$("#combobox").change(function() {
    var curVal=$(this).val();
    $("#combobox").combobox("autocomplete",curVal); 
});
```

There needed to be a function to handle the change of the combobox select field.  On change it will run the combobox function with the autocomplete value of the currently selected option in #combobox.

Comment: the solution you provide above is already working for me. I want to set the value of autocomplete input using jquery. Please see this jfiddle where value is assigned to autocomplete in two ways. [Please see set the java value](http://jsfiddle.net/BbWza/2/)