# set value to jquery(ver 1.7) autocomplete combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete

I'm trying to use jquery autocomplete combobox (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox), now I have problem, how to set values autocomplete combobox?

Example from this list:

```
  <select id="combobox">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
    <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
    <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
    <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
    <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
    <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
    <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
    <option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
    <option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
    <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="Scala">Scala</option>
    <option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
  </select>
```

I want to set value "**Erlang**" to combobox, how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set value to jquery autocomplete combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197664/set-value-to-jquery-autocomplete-combobox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `selected` attribute to the `option` element as you would do with any normal HTML `select` element as shown below:

```
<option value="Erlang" selected="selected">Erlang</option>
```